# Simple job scheduler for single server

Tags: linux, scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling, slurm

I have a single  server shared among different users and I need to set up a simple workload manager/job scheduling system that would allow to share resources fairly among different users. What I'm looking for is a multi-user version of [task spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/) with some added functionality. Ideally, it should

- allow different users to add job to one or multiple queues
- each job should have a maximum walltime after which it is killed, and the next job in the queue is executed
- handle "fairness" in the usage of resources (at minimum, it should cycle among different users)
- allow for multiple job to run at the same time if need be (so if one user has a serial job the other users can take advantage of free resources)

I have found a number of job schedulers (as SLURM or Torque) that could fit the job, but they seem to have a steep learning curve and have a configuration and administration overheard which is way too big for a single server.

Any idea of what could work best?

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question and questions in the same vein pop up on this site regularly. Yet it seems off-topic since it falls into the category of "Questions to recommend a tool". That means that relevance of answers would erode with time, which is not good. I suggest you formulate a question differently, e.g. "Is it possible to configure SLURM to manage a single host?"

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea - but I'd rather not have to put up with SLURM anyway, it's a complicated piece of infrastructure which is not really designed for my needs. If  people have a way to make it a bit more straightforward I'll be happy to try it however :)

Answer (score 1):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) might help. We use celery for running tasks both in single and distributed servers. We can modify as per our needs like adding UI with [Flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshots.html)

Comment: Thank you - I'm having a look, it looks like it's not really designed to handle jobs as shell commands is it?